# How do I include depth when selecting vertices in a specific area?

Tags: vertices, select

I just did a bunch of loop cuts. Now i want to select only the vertices in a specific area, but it only selects the vertices I can "see", like it's 2D. Do I have to rotate the image and slowly select each vertices I want, or is there a shortcut key to select the vertices in front and behind without having to rotate around an object?

Comment: If you just want to select the vertices on one of the loops, hold down the ALT key and click on the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to wireframe mode (Press Z and select wireframe from the pie menu). Can also be toggled from the top of the Viewport. Alternatively, you can also toggle X-ray mode from the same area of the viewport:

[image: Wire]